# How to populate denormalized NoSQL views

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, denormalization

I have a todo app built with Firestore NoSQL db.

The data in the database is query-oriented denormalized data.

I wonder what the best way to populate new views in the db after there is already prod data for some of the other queries.

Example:

In the todo app, the data structure is like this initially:

- userid

  - plan

    - todo items

Now I want to create another page called inbox, for todo items that are not planned

The structure is now:

- userid

  - plan

    - todo items
  - inbox

    - todo items

This would require me to populate the inbox with todo items that are not queried.

Or any feedback on how this might be done in a better way?

Comment: "This would require me to populate the inbox with todo items that are not queried." What do you mean by "not queried"? In other words, how do you precisely differentiate the ones that should go to `plan` and the ones that should go to `inbox`?

Comment: Inbox are for the todo items that don't have a date.